# ExtJs Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeCls' of undefined

Tags: extjs

I have an error when automatically load an Store data for a Grid and select records.

I hope somebody could help me because I tried many way of fix this and I cant...

I receive this error:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeCls' of undefined

This is the context... I have 3 grids each of those have an Store and a Ext.selection.CheckboxModel. The third grid depends from de records selected (checked troght the selection checkbox model) in the second grid to load its information and after the information is loaded it marks (using the his own selection checkbox model) some records. The same happens with the second grid that depends in the first one lets say a kind of cascade where the main information comes from the user having access to some countries (first grid), and based on the countries where he has access I load the information of the states that belongs to the counstries where the user has access and once the information of those states is loaded I select those states where the user has access and so on to continue with the cities.

Thank you

Comment: Like CD.. said, share some code or even better, try to create your scenario at https://fiddle.sencha.com

Answer (score 0):

I finally could resolved the issue... What happened is that according to the description of the problem I have 3 grid one depending of other but those grids are inside a collapsable panel so the user can only see one grid at a time and that was the problem affecting my logic because I was loading each grid and after that checking (marking) the records that the user have automatically but only the firs panel with the first grid was expand... so basically what I had to do is load the information from the first grid, then select (check) the record needed and continue loading the information of the next grid... but before check its records now I expand the panel with this grid so it dont throw the error because as it is no visible at the time I check the record was giving me the error... as a matter of fact I dont like this solution but at least it is working now... THANKS!!!